Can $f(x)$ be exist where $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(x+t)$ is not equal to $\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(0+t)$? To put it simply, $f((0+)+(0+)) \neq f(0+)$
There are countless functions whose function values ​​and right-hand limits are different. However, when thinking about a function that only takes the function values ​​of the right-hand limits of all $x$, I wonder if there exists a case where the function values ​​and right-hand limits are different.
If we express it in words, it is as follows. Let $$g(x)=\lim_{t\to 0^+}f(x+t)$$ Is there an $f(x)$ such that $$g(0) \neq \lim_{x\to 0^+}g(x)$$ (It doesn't have to be at $x=0$, it can be any constant)
I didn't assumed $f(x+)$ exists. I want to know whether there is any function that satisfies the condition. So it’s different with this question Is the ''right limit'' function always right continuous?

I came up with $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if}\ x>t \ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Can this be okay?

@user1317348 Your $f$ is not well-defined; it depends on a dummy variable $t$, used in the limit expression.

Observe that $0^+ +0^+=0^+$

You cannot find any function $f$ verifying that. The reason is that if a function is continuous at a point, it is absolutely continuous on a neighbourhoud of that point.
As $g(0)$ exists, we have: $$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists\alpha>0\mid
0<x<\alpha\implies \lvert f(x) - g(0)\rvert<\varepsilon$$
Let us consider an arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$, the above formula guarantees that we can find $\alpha>0$ verifying the property.
Let us now take a number $x\in[0;\frac\alpha 2)$. We have of course $\lvert f(x) - g(0)\rvert<\varepsilon$.
On the other hand, $g(x) = \lim_{x^+} f$. So we have $$0<t<\frac\alpha 2\implies 0<t+x<\alpha \implies \lvert f(t+x)- g(0)\rvert<\varepsilon
\implies \lvert g(x)- g(0)\rvert\le\varepsilon$$
because $g(x)$ must be contained in the closure of $\{f(x+t), 0<=t<\alpha'\}$ for any $\alpha'>0$ by the definition of a right limit.
We can now conclude. Consider an arbitratry $\varepsilon >0$, we have $\epsilon' = \frac\varepsilon 2>0$. We can find $\alpha'>0$ verifying $0<x<\alpha'\implies \lvert f(x) - g(0)\rvert<\varepsilon'$
We have shown $0<x< \frac{\alpha'}2\implies \lvert g(x)- g(0)\rvert\le\varepsilon'<\varepsilon$. So for $\alpha=\frac{\alpha'}2$,
we have finally $0<x<\alpha\implies \lvert g(x) - g(0)\rvert<\varepsilon$
As $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, we have shown $\lim_{0^+}{g} = g(0)$: $g$ is right continuous at $0$.
